# Give a recurrence relations & base cases for the number of $n$ digit decimal strings containing an even number of $0$ digits.

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Give a recurrence relations & base cases for the number of $n$ digit decimal strings containing an even number of $0$ digits.

My solution is:

Let $a_n$ denote the the number of $n$ digit numbers containing an even number of $0$ digits.
$a_n = (9a_{n-1}) + (10^{n-1}-a_{n-1}) = 8a_{n-1}+10^{n-1}$.

Is the solution correct? What is the initial condition?

Comment: Please include the question statement inside the question body.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean decimal strings, where leading zeros are permitted, your recurrence is good.  It would be good to explain the logic behind it.  The $9a_{n-1}$ term takes a string of length $n-1$ and appends a non-zero digit to it.  The $10^{n-1}-a_{n-1}$ term takes an unacceptable string of length $n-1$ (which must have an odd number of zeros) and appends a zero to get an acceptable string of length $n$.

The bases case is just a place to start that you compute some other way.  If you imagine computing $a_3$, you need $a_2$ to do that.  To compute $a_2,$ you need $a_1$.  It is easy to count $a_1$ by hand-there are $9$ strings of length $1$ that have an even number of zeros.  That can be your base case.  It also works to take $a_0$ as your base case.  There is one string of length $0$ that has an even number of zeros-the empty string.  It works fine, as it gives $a_1=8(1)+10^0=9$